# Vba: getting all cells from a given row matching a given string

Tags: vba, string, match, offset

I am given a row of cells and a string to match. I want to know the positions where the string appears. I ideally need to have it in a vector in vba.

I am trying to loop over all the occurrencies of "Name To Match" over the row starting on the cell corresponding to the variable.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
myIndex = 0
While myIndex < maxIndexAllowed
    myIndex = Match("Name To Match", Offset(Range("beginRowToInspect"), 0, myIndex, 1, maxIndexAllowed), 0) + myIndex
Wend
```

conceptually this is fine. But I get this error: "sub or function not defined" and the keyword Offset appears to be highlighted.

Bonus: I would be happy if I could get rid of maxIndexAllowed.

Comment: You need to know every position where the match is found? If so a dictionary is the way to make it fast (If there are no permutations on UCase/LCase or not exact matches)

Comment: @Damian, yes. I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindAllMatches()

    Dim Matches As New Scripting.Dictionary 'Need the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference to work
    Dim C As Range
    Dim Col As Byte
    Dim RowToInspect As Long
    Dim NameToMatch As String

    RowToInspect = 2 'here is were you set the row to inspect
    NameToMatch = "x" 'here is were you set your string to match

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'change MySheet for your working sheet
        Col = .Cells(RowToInspect, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column on your row to inspect
        For Each C In .Range(.Cells(RowToInspect, 1), .Cells(RowToInspect, Col))
            If Not Matches.Exists(C.Value) Then
                Matches.Add C.Value, C.Column 'First match we add the item and its column
            Else
                Matches(C.Value) = Matches(C.Value) & "," & C.Column 'Later matches will add the columns separated by ", "
            End If
        Next C
    End With

    If Matches.Exists(NameToMatch) Then
        MsgBox "The columns for " & NameToMatch & " that were found are: " & Matches(NameToMatch)
    Else
        MsgBox NameToMatch & " was not found on row: " & RowToInspect
    End If

End Sub
```